# Swift Admob reward based video ad integration and testing

Tags: swift, admob, interstitial

I've successfully been able to integrate both banner ads and image based interstitial ads into my applications with no problems.

I'm considering adding a reward based video ad however I'm not sure if I can simply set up the code as per the interstitial ad but change the adUnitID to that of the rewarded video ad I set up in Admob?

When I do just that the test ad showing an interstitial therefore I can't tell if a video would display.

I'm finding very little guidance to follow online with regard to setting it up this way.

This is what I currently use:

```
    func loadAndShow3() {



    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID, "XXXX"]
    myAd = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "XXXX")
    myAd.delegate = self
    myAd.load(request)



}

func interstitialDidReceiveAd(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {

    if (self.myAd.isReady) {

        myAd.present(fromRootViewController: self)



    }
 func displayAd() {



    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "loadAndShow"), object: nil)


}
```

Comment: What is your question? Can you edit your question to clarify please.

Comment: If I add in an ad unit ID for a rewarded video ad into the above code would it work?

Comment: No. Look at the docs: [Rewarded Video](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/rewarded-video).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code would not work. You would have to make a new request for a GADRewardBasedVideoAd instead of the GADRequest(). There is a really good tutorial made by Google at how to do that attached below. If you follow the tutorial it's a rather straight forward solution. Best of luck to you.

[Google's tutorial](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rewarded-video).